# su command with -p or -m flags

Tags: su

What is the difference between the following su commands?

```
su -m
su -p
```

I know that both flags are used to preserve the current environment but I don’t know the differences if there are any.

Answer (score 2):

There are no differences, they are just different options for the same behaviour. They probably come from different older versions of `su` that implemented one of these options with the same behaviour.

From the man page:

```
 -m, -p, --preserve-environment
     Preserve the current environment, except for:

     $PATH
         reset according to the /etc/login.defs options ENV_PATH or
         ENV_SUPATH (see below);

     $IFS
         reset to “<space><tab><newline>”, if it was set.

     If the target user has a restricted shell, this option has no
     effect (unless su is called by root).
```

Comment: Actually I observed some differences using different flags (m or p). I have a script which behaves differently if I use -m than if I use -p.

Comment: And your man page says it is the same? What version of su? On which system? Does `su --help` give an difference for the two?

Comment: I don’t have access to the system now. Tomorrow I will check the su version etc.

Comment: Ok, my information is from Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @Anthon: There is no man page available in the linux version I am using but according to --help output it says "-m, --preserve-environment   do not reset environment variables -p  same as -m". And the linux version I am using is: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP2.